# Javascript onclick even on a div not working

Tags: javascript

I have a div and when a user clicks on it using the `onclick` event, i'm calling a function:

```
   function test(a)
    {   

     alert(a);
   }

<div onclick="javascript:test('zaswde');">sdfasdasdadasdasds</div>​
```

**Update**

```
    <ul>
      <li> 
           <div>
       <div onclick="javascript:alert('v'); "></div>

           </div>
            <div ></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Can't i use `onclick` on the div element?
​

Comment: How are you attaching the `onclick`?

Comment: How about you show us the whole code? Specifically the div with its onclick code. Is this function above or below that in the HTML? What errors does the console give?

Comment: Your code is fine. You have some error somewhere else

Comment: @Jalpesh Patel:update my html.

Comment: In its simplest form, the code works. [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/owebim/1/). You'll have to provide more info/code.

Comment: In your update the div is empty so there's nothing to click on.  In your original there may be some other error in the same script block as `test()` that prevents it working. In both versions you can omit the `javascript:` label. Is `test()` a global function? (It needs to be.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Onclick will call the function, you don't need the `javascript:`

```
<div onclick="test('zaswde');">sdfasdasdadasdasds</div>​
```

Comment: But having `javascript:` additionally wouldn't break that code. So even with `javascript:` it should work.

Comment: `javascript:` should be used in attributes that expect a URL, such as `HREF` attribute of `A` tag. Does it really work to put it in an attribute that expects JavaScript code?

Comment: @Barmar: yes it works. So - removing it wouldn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine.

Moreover You may use click events on any element including `<div>`

```
<div onclick="test('This is a <div> tag');">Click on this &lt;div&gt; element</div>

<span onclick="test('This is a <span> tag');">Click on this &lt;span&gt;</span>

<p onclick="test('This is a <p> tag');">Click on this &lt;p&gt;</p>

<a href="#" onclick="test('This is an <a> tag');">Click on this &lt;a&gt;</a>
```

[**See An Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/7ugRZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your code will work. But most would argue that it is not the best way to write it.

I guess the reason why it is not working is because you already have a JavaScript error in your HTML page. Check the error console in your browser and see if there are any JavaScript error on it. If yes, then fix that and then this should work.

Edit:

I also see from your example that you don't have anything inside the div. So how are you sure that you are clicking inside the div. See if you can add a senstence or two inside the div, so that you get enough space to click inside the div.

Comment: I created http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Eyk86/ with his original code, console says 'test is not defined'.

Comment: @Barmar - In your fiddle you've defined `test()` inside the onload event handler, so it's not accessible from an onclick attribute that can only see global functions. Try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/Eyk86/1/ (note the fiddle options on the left - I've changed it from "onLoad" to "no wrap").